# Tooltip binding behaving differently when set as property in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is a bit of a strange question, but more for my understanding than anything else.  I have a tooltip on a button set up as follows

```
<ContentControl MouseDown="ContentControl_MouseDown" ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="10000" x:Name="contentControl1" ToolTip="{Binding Text}" >
    <Button Focusable="True" x:Name="Btn1" Command="{Binding CommandToExecute}" Tag="{Binding Text}" Foreground="{x:Null}" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="true">
        <shellModule:AutoGreyableImage  Source="{Binding Image}" />
    </Button>
</ContentControl>
```

with the following in the background.

```
    private void ContentControl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (contentControl1.ToolTip != null)
        {
            if (contentControl1.ToolTip is ToolTip)
            {
                var castToolTip = (ToolTip)contentControl1.ToolTip;
                castToolTip.IsOpen = true;
            }
            else
            {
                toolTip.Content = contentControl1.ToolTip;
                toolTip.IsOpen = true;
            }
        }
        Timer.Start();
    }
```

This tooltip works perfectly fine, and binds as expected.  However if I instead declare the tooltip like so.

```
<ContentControl MouseDown="ContentControl_MouseDown" ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="10000" x:Name="contentControl1" >
    <ContentControl.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Content="{Binding Path=Text}" />
    </ContentControl.ToolTip>
    <Button Focusable="True" x:Name="Btn1" Command="{Binding CommandToExecute}" Tag="{Binding Text}" Foreground="{x:Null}" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="true">
        <shellModule:AutoGreyableImage  Source="{Binding Image}" />
    </Button>
</ContentControl>
```

the binding no longer works.  Now it doesn't matter too much since it's already doing what I need it to do for now.  (all this tooltip will ever do is display strings, I'm assuming I can still split them with /n) I'm just wondering what makes it behave differently between the two implementations, I'd have thought the two would be somewhat equivalent to one another.

Comment: Because you're trying to pass the value of a dependency property on `Button` to the parent `ContentControl` which doesn't know nor care about the properties of it's children. It would work if you made it `Content="{Binding Path=Tag, ElementName=Btn1}` but I wouldn't suggest doing it that way. There's easier ways to accomplish your desired result with no codebehind and avoid other confusion in things like why you expect `Text` to return anything from binding since it's not property on either Button or ContentControl in the first place...

Comment: The reason for the codebehind is because of a set of requirements on the button.  The button gets disabled based on a set of conditions (hardware positions, parameter settings) and when disabled, needs to display why it's been disabled so the operator can fix it.  The button needs to display the popup on click, not on hover etc, that's why all the codebehind stuff.  I do agree there may be a simpler way of handling it all, but with all my google-fu and the set of constraints on the UI, this is the best I could come up with.